# Obtain the product key of Microsoft Office?

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-office, reinstall, license-key

I have to reformat my daughters laptop which has Windows Vista Home Edition...
It currently has Microsoft Office on it which I will have to reinstall, but I can find the licenses number...
Is there a way I can find the license number on the PC before I reformat it?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can use the [Magic Jellybean Keyfinder Tool](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) to extract product keys for software already installed on the machine.

Comment: Googling "product key recovery" will find many more

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/productkeysactivation/tp/topkeyfinder.htm) quite a good list of free key finding programs with descriptions and download links. I used number three just today for Office 2007 and it worked nicely. Just perform Tools -> Search and your product key should show up.