# Find and locate Microsoft Office 2010 key

Tags: microsoft-office

When I had my old hard drive, a copy of Microsoft Office 2010 was installed on it. I changed my hard drive but I still have the old one - now I want to locate the serial number (activation key) which was used to activate Office 2010.

When the software is installed, I usually use programs like Magic Jelly Keyfinder, but the problem is that Office 2010 is installed in my old HDD.

Is it possible to find the key in the folders and files?

Comment: "the problem is that Office 2010 is installed on my old HDD" ... How do you plan to read the files and data on this drive?

Comment: I installed it as a second HDD ( drive E) in my computer, I can view all files

Comment: if you had purchased the office, you should have the key on box or inside the box. pardon the "if"; not all people use licenced copies..

Comment: It was already installed on the computer when I bought it , I dont have the disk , I want to know which version was installed and what key was used so I can download it from microsoft site and re-install it

Comment: So your copy of Office was provided by the OEM then? If you have all of your documentation from the manufacturer, the key should be somewhere in it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain the product key of Microsoft Office?](http://superuser.com/questions/165976/obtain-the-product-key-of-microsoft-office)

Answer (score 4):

[Produkey has a function](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) to load a registry hive from another OS that is offline, it may do what you need.

.
[image]

.
[image]

Comment: I've used this before with much success.

Comment: @Moab When I load the hive I get `Error 1314 Required Privilege Not Held`