# How to find the actual product key of Microsoft Office 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, license, product-key

Where can I find the actual product key of Microsoft Office 2010 ? I use Windows 8 and When I try to open Excel 2010 unlicensed product message appears and need to 25 character input to open it .

I check topic of you and I used SoftKey Revealer . Scan and found my office key . It matches . It says configures but still there is no result . When I open a new page I saw this message again '' microsoft office 2010 trial version , 1- I want to activate the software over the internet 2- I do not want to activate my copy. Instead, now I want to convert to the full product'' . When I write the product key of my office ( I found it via SoftKey Revealer ). Its loading and seems like activated then I open a new excel page and still same warning and no result . What can I do to activate it?

WARNING STEP 1 :

[image]

WARNING STEP 2 :

[image]

**PLEASE SEE ALSO WARNING STEP 3 , WARNING STEP 4 AND WARNING STEP 5 SCREENSHOTS IN COMMENTS**

Comment: Help about in all Microsoft products should show you the product key.  This of course is not the installer key.

Comment: @Optichip It is not the original version and needs product key to use

Comment: Similar: [Find and locate Microsoft Office 2010 key](http://superuser.com/questions/422239/find-and-locate-microsoft-office-2010-key?rq=1)

Comment: I check topic and I used SoftKey Revealer . Scan and found my office key . It matches . It says configures but still there is no result . I cant activate my office 2010 .

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has a web page that shows you how to locate your product keys on the packaging of your purchased product.  You can find the information on locating it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150115114046/http://products.office.com/en-us/2010-microsoft-office-suites-license-designations):

> **Traditional disc:** If you purchased a full boxed version from Microsoft, a retail store, reseller or online retailer and the software disc came in a shrink-wrapped package, the Product Key should be located inside the package on a label on a card opposite the disc holder on the left side of the DVD case.
>
> **Product Key Card:** If you purchased a Product Key Card from Microsoft, a retail store, reseller, or online retailer the Product Key should be located inside the package on a label on the left side of the case.

If you have Volume licensing you can get product keys from the [Volume Licensing Website](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/).  Here's another [Microsoft page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-do-I-recover-or-replace-a-lost-Microsoft-Office-product-key-e76cd471-ab49-4142-aedc-fb8f8c43ea81?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) that gives you even more options on how to obtain a license key in the event that you have lost yours.

Comment: The option I think you're overlooking is you'll need to call Microsoft and pay for a new code if you don't have the one that came with the machine.  If this was a trial version, you would need to purchase a full license from Microsoft.

Comment: I check topic of you and I used SoftKey Revealer . Scan and found my office key . It matches . It says configures but still there is no result . When i opne a new page i saw this message again '' microsoft office 2010 trial version , 1- I want to activate the software over the internet 2- I do not want to activate my copy. Instead, now I want to convert to the full product'' . When i write the product key of my office ( I found it via SoftKey Revealer ). Its loading and seems like activated then I open a new excel page and still smae warning and no result . What can I do to activate it?

Comment: WARNING STEP 3 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/sK2Ww.png ( PRODUCT KEY OF ME SoftKey Revealer matches and loading ) 


WARNING STEP 4 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/MM3x4.png ( resturn to  back and When I said to cancel to this, WARNING STEP 5 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/8jMDJ.png . )

Comment: @JohnNash sounds like your "free trial" period is over and you need to purchase the software.

Comment: Is there any way to activate or get it from internet without purchase ? @Optichip

Comment: At this point if you don't want to purchase it I would switch to a free solution like OpenOffice or similar.

Comment: @JohnNash - In other words, you want to know how to steal Microsoft Office?

Comment: Then go to whomever passes out the licenses at the U where you are a student and see if you qualify.